# macOs: Get the Current Memory used an application from the PID

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, heap-memory

Language: C++
Plataform: Mac Os - OsX-10.10.3

Given a PID from an already running application, return the current allocated memory.

Basically I would like something like:

```
  double getMemoryForPID( long pid )
```

This is easy on linux, and Windows. But somehow I could not find how to implement this for mac os.

Note: I found code to return the current memory for the current application. But this is not what I want. Basically, I am writing a alocated memory profiler -